# Как редактировать single-product в woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Столкнулся с тем, что нужно кастомизировать страничку, которая открывается при переходе на товар(Single-Product). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно будет ее кастомизировать? Верстка есть. Вставлять верстку и использовать хуки? Или эту страницу по другому нужно кастомизировать?

Answer (score 0):

Тоже через хуки. Все темплейт парты можно посмотреть в файлах самого плагина в вашей установке, либо в Github репозитории самого WooCommerce.

Comment: А можете подсказать, использую хук woocommerce_product_thumbnails() в файле "single-product.php", который скопировал из основной папки плагина в свою тему. И вот использую, прописываю его и вападает фатальная ошибка: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function woocommerce_product_thumbnails() in C:\OSPanel\OpenServer\domains\womazing\wp-content\themes\womazing\woocommerce\single-product.php:74 Stack trace: #0........."

Comment: А можете подсказать, каким образом вы его используете? Потому что видимо вы его используете как функцию, а не как хук. Это же говорится и в тексте ошибки. Если вы его используете в файлу single-product.php, то вызов должен выглядеть таким образом `do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' );`

Comment: @Simon я извинюсь, пришлось отойти. Я вставил верстку своего item`a, там внутри тега к примеру открываю <?php woocommerce_product_thumbnails(); ?>. Сейчас попробовал как написали вы - такая же ошибка. Не пойму никак

Comment: Ну начнем наверное с того, зачем использовать внутри файла single-product.php woocommerce_product_thumbnails, потому что сам файл, как таковой, для подгрузки контента служит, можно посмотреть в коде [темплейта](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product.php) возможно посмотрите данное [видео](https://youtu.be/-3rmeTbEQrU) может вам что-то прояснит, там как раз о странице товара идет речь